# Java Screensaver Mac

Tags: java, macos, screensaver

I was just wondering if there was a way to turn a simple JFrame program in java into a native mac screensaver. I saw a similar post for windows, but it wasn't helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

If there is, it would not be simple.  In fact, I suspect the 'post for windows' you refer to (it would have been handy to include a link) is talking about the SaverBeans API, which disappeared a long time ago.  :(

Comment: I think it did, actually. After a little research, I think it would be better just to learn how to do it in native cocoa or something.

Comment: You can but it's not necessary, i just used Launch4j to convert java code to exe then renamed it to .scr and voilà. However that only works for windows, for Mac it's hard =v

Answer (score 0):

I've built screensavers for both Windows and Mac OS and no, there won't be a simple way of achieving that. The reason is that screensavers on Mac OS are dynamic libraries. You need to provide Mac OS with a library that has various entry points, that is, functions, that it will call to start the screensaver.

You could theoretically wrap your Java application on a library, but it'd be extremely complex at the very least.

Comment: Does this answer your question?